# What is the reason of using spread operator to get actions?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Why we can get actions without using spread operator when we have just one property? And why we can not get actions without using spread operator when we have more than one property?

In other words:

Why this is true

```js
methods:{
mapActions(["fetchImages"])
},
```

But this is not true:

```js
methods:{
mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
a:10
},
```

Comment: You have to use the spread operator in both cases (your "true" case is not really valid). And it doesn't make sense to add a data field in `methods` in your second case.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `mapActions` will return an object, if you return the object directly to methods, it means that object will be the methods. But if you want to add more functions to methods, you have to merge them, because that we use the spred operator.

1) this does not work, you don't have any key for the object of mapActions returns

```js
methods:{
  mapActions(["fetchImages"])
},

//result
{{fetchImages: function(){...}}}
```

2) methods will be an object with the fetchImages function inside

```js
methods: mapActions(["fetchImages"])
// result
{fetchImages: function () {...}}
```

3) methods will be a merged object with the 'fetchImages' function and the 'a' function together

```js
methods: {
...mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
a: function () { return 'a' }
}
// result
{fetchImages: function () {...}, a: function() {...}}
```

4) this is not goig to work, because again we area trying to add an object without key to our methods object

```js
methods: {
mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
a: function () { return 'a' }
}

//result
{{fetchImages: function() {...}}, a: function(){...}}
```

5) for this work or we use the spread operator or add a key for the mapActions result object as below

```js
methods: {
  actions:mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
  a: function () { return 'a' }
}

//result
{ actions: { fetchImages: function() {}}, a: function(){...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point is correct but the example is wrong.

This not true

```js
methods:{
mapActions(["fetchImages"])
},
```

But this is true:

```js
methods: mapActions(["fetchImages"]),
```

mapActions return **Object** contains several methods and you cannot wrap an object with { } like this - it will become putting an object inside another object.

Clear Example:

```js
mapActionsObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

let myMethod = {...mapActionsObj}  // myMethod is { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,}

let wrongMethod = {mapActionObj} // wrongMethod is { {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} }
// not what you want
```

Now, come back to your question.

Actually, you can use directly `mapActions` as: `methods: mapActions` without Spread Syntax `...` when you don't have any local method properties.

```js
methods: {
      ...mapActions(['fetchImages']),
    },

methods: mapActions(['fetchImages']),
```

Both of above do exactly the same thing!

But when you do have any local method property, then you need Spread Syntax.

It because the mapActions returns an object. And then we need Object Spread Operator to merge multiple Objects into one.

```js
methods: {
  localMethod () { /* ... */ },
  // we use ... Spread Operator here to merge the local method object with outer object
  ...mapActions(['deleteAll']),
}
```

The same happens to `mapGetters`, `mapState`.

The [Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) explains this quite clear, but not in mapGetter sbut the first thing: mapState.